# dynamic initialization of list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, function, dynamic, initialization

Let's say that I want to create a function that takes a list of a  number of lists with integers as its values, but every list can have a different size. For example, the following list of lists as input parameter: `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7],[8,9]]` but other input parameter can be: `[1,2],[3,4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12,13]`

Then I want to return another list of lists, with the same number of lists as the input but with different number of elements on each list, because I want to do some kind of algorithm to remove some elements of each list.

Is it possible to initialize the list of lists inside the function in a dynamic way using Python?. I can only think about first create a fixed number of lists with a fixed size.

Comment: *"I can only think about first create a fixed number of lists with a fixed size"* - How would that look like?

Comment: @Woodford Not random as a probability, I mean that each time the function input parameter can be different.

Comment: @KellyBundy Edited: I mean to create the same fixed number of lists as the input parameter, and the set a fixed size by iterating over the input lists.

Comment: The use of random numbers was to demonstrate creating a list of variable sized lists. Use whatever fixed values you want.

Comment: What does "because I want to do some kind of algorithm to remove some elements of each list" refer to? Do you mean the input lists or the lists you're creating? Why is that a reason why you need to initialize the lists with a different size than the input lists?

Comment: `new_list = [[0]*some_algorithm(x) for x in input_list]`. This uses an algorithm based on the original lists to produce the output lists.

Answer (score 0):

I **assume** you have as input a `input_list:list of lists`, and you want to output the possibilities of `possibility:list of lists` having:

- every integers of `input_list`
- the same number of inner lists as `input_list`: k

You can get the possibilities of lengths of sublists of `possibility`, then charge every sublist with the integers of `input_list`.

> Let the lengths of sublists of `possibility`: `filling_possibility = [len_1, len_2, ..., len_k]`.
>
>  We can also write it like that: f = (x_1, x_2, ..., x_k)
>
>  Let n the number of integers. We want every integers, so:
>
>  n = x_0 + x_1 + ... + x_k
>
>  We can remark that:
>
>  n = x_0 + (x_1 + ... + x_k)
>
>  n = x_0 + x_1 + (x_2 + ... + x_k)
>
>  etc
>
>  And we know how to resolve n = x_0, so we can use a recursion:

```py
def resolve_equation(n, k):
    def find_solutions_recursive(target, k, current_solution):
        if k == 1:
            current_solution.append(target)
            solutions.append(tuple(current_solution))
            current_solution.pop()
        else:
            for x in range(target + 1):
                current_solution.append(x)
                find_solutions_recursive(target - x, k - 1, current_solution)
                current_solution.pop()

    solutions = []
    find_solutions_recursive(n, k, [])
    return solutions

input_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]
n = sum(map(len, input_list))
k = len(input_list)
filling_possibilities = resolve_equation(n, k)

print(filling_possibilities)
```

Now we charge every `filling_possibility` with permutations of the list of integers of `input_list`.
The permutations can be described using itertools:

```py
import itertools

integers = sum(input_list, [])
integers_distributions = itertools.permutations(integers)

print(list(integers_distributions))
```

And the charging part, for the same integer distribution as `input_list`:

```py
filling = filling_possibilities[0]
# Distribute integers to the current `possibility`
possibility = [[] for _ in range(k)]
# the index in the list of integers `integers`
i = 0
for sublist_len, sublist in zip(filling, possibility):
    sublist.extend(integers[i:i+sublist_len])
    i += sublist_len

print(possibility)
```

All mixed together:

```py
import itertools

def resolve_equation(n, k):
    def find_solutions_recursive(target, k, current_solution):
        if k == 1:
            current_solution.append(target)
            solutions.append(tuple(current_solution))
            current_solution.pop()
        else:
            for x in range(target + 1):
                current_solution.append(x)
                find_solutions_recursive(target - x, k - 1, current_solution)
                current_solution.pop()

    solutions = []
    find_solutions_recursive(n, k, [])
    return solutions

def mix_integers(input_list):
    n = sum(map(len, input_list))
    k = len(input_list)
    filling_possibilities = resolve_equation(n, k)
    integers = sum(input_list, [])

    possibilities = []
    for filling in filling_possibilities:
        # `integers_distributions` is exhausted on every iteration (generator)
        integers_distributions = itertools.permutations(integers)
        for distribution in integers_distributions:
            # Distribute integers to the current `possibility`
            possibility = [[] for _ in range(k)]
            # i is the index in the list of integers `distribution`
            i = 0
            for sublist_len, sublist in zip(filling, possibility):
                sublist.extend(distribution[i:i+sublist_len])
                i += sublist_len
            possibilities.append(possibility)
    return possibilities

mixed = mix_integers([[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6, 7]])
print(mixed)
```

But it is *very* slow. You may try it with `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9]]`.